# How to clone the object in Automation Anywhere when both objects have same properties?

Tags: automationanywhere

I am new to Automation Anywhere. I want to clone 2 different tables of single web-site.
The problem is that both tables have same html-ID and the object cloning feature of automation anywhere clones the 1st table it gets and skips the 2nd one. 
Both table have same structure, same css class and same html-ID.

I want to fetch 2nd table columns but it is cloning 1st table columns.

Any kind of help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Both tables will have different Path & DOMXPath properties[image: object_cloning]

Just lock onto the paths instead of the properties. Object cloning is only capable of retrieving the first item that matches all of the properties you've chosen. The paths will be different. Use variables in place of the values if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this is to use DOMXPath and/or Path properties to distinctly identify the correct table in this case. Otherwise, if the second table has an attribute like class that is different from the first one, then that can be used to identify it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).